# which is this plugin ?

Tags: plugins, rating, comments

can somebody tell me which is this plugin used in comment rating ?

http://goo.gl/AWxl5 see on comment

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The plugin dir is `commentsvote`, which matches [this Comments Vote plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/commentsvote/), though I'm not sure it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try: [Comment Rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-rating/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a modded version of [Comment Rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-rating/) plugin